# How to add live camera filters and color effects in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, filter, camera, webgl

Is there a way to add live camera filters and color effects like contrast, brightness, sepia etc in react native ? Trying to use expo-gl or web-gl. But no luck yet. Camera component does not render inside shader node using web-gl.

Does any one know a solution for this or developed this type of functionality before. It would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Expo has a demo for using shaders on the live camera feed hidden in their repo: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/apps/native-component-list/src/screens/GL/GLCameraScreen.tsx

You should be able to do what you're trying to do by messing around with the fragment shader.